# Search date in the view - ASP NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

my problem is that I can not find date complete in view for example only "2018" and not "2018-01-01"

**in my controller**

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.FechaFinal))
{
    odontologosInternoes = odontologosInternoes
                               .Where(m => m.FechaFinal.ToString()
                                   .Contains(view.FechaFinal.ToString()))
                               .ToList();
}
```

Comment: Need more details about odontologosInternoes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `FechaFinal` is of DateTime type, try converting it to string with your specific date time format as parameter.

Ex:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.FechaFinal))
{
    odontologosInternoes = odontologosInternoes
                               .Where(m => m.FechaFinal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")
                                   .Contains(view.FechaFinal.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")))
                               .ToList();
}
```

If you do `.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")` on your `FechaFinal` it should give you `"2018-01-01"`.

Answer (score 0):

I think this could help you:-

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(view.FechaFinal))
{
    odontologosInternoes = odontologosInternoes
                               .Where(m => m.FechaFinal.Value.Year
                                   .Equals(view.FechaFinal.Value.Year))
                               .ToList();
}
```